# BrowserStackLocal get exception with message Disconnected

Tags: php, codeception, acceptance-testing, browserstack

I trying test with codeception and browserstack.

1. Clone this repo https://github.com/browserstack/codeception-browserstack
2. Download addons browserstacklocal.exe on local test
3. Run browserstacklocal.exe with my key
4. Run local test

Have this error http://petrvolny.eu/error.png

Comment: Please copy error output as text instead of providing screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the logging is the problem, after removing `--log-file` in the library source it worked fine. Also make sure you are providing a key.

I know you are using PHP, but for anyone using Javacsript with node, here is a little patch:

```
let fs = require('fs');
const file = 'node_modules/browserstack-local/lib/Local.js';

fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function(err, contents) {
  var result = contents.replace("['--daemon', this.opcode, '--log-file', this.logfile]", "['--daemon', this.opcode]");
  fs.writeFile(file, result);
});
```

Hope this helps in some way! I know editing the library source is not good, but I found it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used BrowserStack, but I did a quick search -
`BrowserStack\LocalException` with message `D` looks wrong.

`D` is probably the first letter of the real exception message.

This issue could be caused by this code: https://github.com/browserstack/browserstack-local-php/blob/491c6e31960ce8111d2cb70cb84d03e73f270dbb/lib/Local.php#L125

```
throw new LocalException($data['message']['message']);
```

It used to be `$data['message']` but it was changed a year ago: 
https://github.com/browserstack/browserstack-local-php/pull/11/files

My advice is to edit `vendor/browserstack/browserstack-local/lib/Local.php`
and change that line to `throw new LocalException($data['message']);` to see what the underlying cause is.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.
After modify have this full error:
http://petrvolny.eu/error2.png
But my browserstacklocal is online:(

Comment: Please modify your question to say that you get exception with message Disconnected.